# Cannot serialize AnonymousUser object using Django Rest Framework - missing attributes

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make available the current user object so my AJAX front-end can determine if the user is logged in or not.

The current user is either an instance of `dajngo.contrib.auth.User` for logged in people or `AnonymousUser` for non-logged in people. The serializer is as follows,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many = True, view_name = 'comment-detail')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'comments', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

with the following view

```
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    '''
    Returns the current user, logged in or not
    '''
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This serializer works fine for logged in users i.e. it patches on the 'comments' field and sends it off. However for `AnonymousUser` it chokes. It claims that there is no method 'comments' (which there isn't but it should be patched on right?) and if I remove the 'comments' requirement from `fields` it then complains about no 'first_name'.

Is this an issue with `AnonymousUser` not being an instance of `django.contrib.auth.User`? If so, how do I remedy it?

I realise I could check at the View level and return a custom data object if it is an instance of `AnonymousUser` but is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to serialize like this, moving authentication check to backend (where it belongs):

```
{
    'is_logged_in': True,
    'user': <<serialized user>>,
}
```

and:

```
{
    'is_logged_in': False,
    'user': None, # or something else like this
}
```

It's common solution in many APIs. Metadata is on top of JSON and possible objects under a key(s). You can check if user is `AnonymousUser` or `User` by checking [.is_authenticated()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) - it's been specially created for such purpose (compare with:
[AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser)).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your view like shown below

```
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    '''
    Returns the current user, logged in or not
    '''
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response([])`
```